# How to reverse django feed url?

Tags: python, django, rss, django-syndication

I've been searching for hours to try and figure this out, and it seems like no one has ever put an example online - I've just created a Django 1.2 rss feed view object and attached it to a url. When I visit the url, everything works great, so I know my implementation of the feed class is OK.

The hitch is, I can't figure out how to link to the url in my template. I could just hard code it, but I would much rather use {% url %}

I've tried passing the full path like so:

```
{% url app_name.lib.feeds.LatestPosts blog_name=name %}
```

And I get nothing. I've been searching and it seems like everyone else has a solution so obvious it's not worth posting online. Have I just been up too long?

Here is the relevent url pattern:

```
from app.lib.feeds import LatestPosts

urlpatterns = patterns('app.blog.views',
    (r'^rss/(?P<blog_name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$', LatestPosts()),
    #snip...
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you urlpattern's look like?

Comment: updated to add the urlpatterns,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [name your url pattern](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2), which requires the use of the `url` helper function:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url, patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('app.blog.views',
    url(r'^rss/(?P<blog_name>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/$', LatestPosts(), name='latest-posts'),
    #snip...
)
```

Then, you can simply use `{% url latest-posts blog_name="myblog" %}` in your template.

Comment: Shouldn't you include the blog_name argument in the url tag?

Comment: Aww crap I guess I was up a bit too late. I tried naming it, but failed on the url helper function. With the addition of the parameter, this works. Thank you!